# How to print a date in a regular format?

Tags: python, datetime, date

This is my code:

```py
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print(today)
```

This prints: `2008-11-22` which is exactly what I want.

But, I have a list I'm appending this to and then suddenly everything goes "wonky". Here is the code:

```py
import datetime
mylist = [datetime.date.today()]
print(mylist)
```

This prints `[datetime.date(2008, 11, 22)]`. How can I get just a simple date like `2008-11-22`?

Comment: **The short answer:** By applying ``str()`` (to each element of the list), because that is just what ``print`` implicitly did to your solo ``today`` object.

Answer (score 1099, accepted):

### The WHY: dates are objects

In Python, dates are objects. Therefore, when you manipulate them, you manipulate objects, not strings or timestamps.

Any object in Python has TWO string representations:

- The regular representation that is used by `print` can be get using the `str()` function. It is most of the time the most common human readable format and is used to ease display. So `str(datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 22, 19, 53, 42))` gives you `'2008-11-22 19:53:42'`.
- The alternative representation that is used to represent the object nature (as a data). It can be get using the `repr()` function and is handy to know what kind of data your manipulating while you are developing or debugging. `repr(datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 22, 19, 53, 42))` gives you `'datetime.datetime(2008, 11, 22, 19, 53, 42)'`.

What happened is that when you have printed the date using `print`, it used `str()` so you could see a nice date string. But when you have printed `mylist`, you have printed a list of objects and Python tried to represent the set of data, using `repr()`.

### The How: what do you want to do with that?

Well, when you manipulate dates, keep using the date objects all long the way. They got thousand of useful methods and most of the Python API expect dates to be objects.

When you want to display them, just use `str()`. In Python, the good practice is to explicitly cast everything. So just when it's time to print, get a string representation of your date using `str(date)`.

One last thing. When you tried to print the dates, you printed `mylist`. If you want to print a date, you must print the date objects, not their container (the list).

E.G, you want to print all the date in a list :

```
for date in mylist :
    print str(date)
```

Note that ***in that specific case***, you can even omit `str()` because print will use it for you. But it should not become a habit :-)

### Practical case, using your code

```
import datetime
mylist = []
today = datetime.date.today()
mylist.append(today)
print mylist[0] # print the date object, not the container ;-)
2008-11-22

# It's better to always use str() because :

print "This is a new day : ", mylist[0] # will work
>>> This is a new day : 2008-11-22

print "This is a new day : " + mylist[0] # will crash
>>> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.date' objects

print "This is a new day : " + str(mylist[0]) 
>>> This is a new day : 2008-11-22
```

### Advanced date formatting

Dates have a default representation, but you may want to print them in a specific format. In that case, you can get a custom string representation using the `strftime()` method.

`strftime()` expects a string pattern explaining how you want to format your date.

E.G :

```
print today.strftime('We are the %d, %b %Y')
>>> 'We are the 22, Nov 2008'
```

All the letter after a `"%"` represent a format for something:

- `%d` is the day number (2 digits, prefixed with leading zero's if necessary)
- `%m` is the month number (2 digits, prefixed with leading zero's if necessary)
- `%b` is the month abbreviation (3 letters)
- `%B` is the month name in full (letters)
- `%y` is the year number abbreviated (last 2 digits)
- `%Y` is the year number full (4 digits)

etc.

[Have a look at the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), or [McCutchen's quick reference](https://strftime.org) you can't know them all.

Since [PEP3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), every object can have its own format used automatically by the method format of any string. In the case of the datetime, the format is the same used in
strftime. So you can do the same as above like this:

```
print "We are the {:%d, %b %Y}".format(today)
>>> 'We are the 22, Nov 2008'
```

The advantage of this form is that you can also convert other objects at the same time.
With the introduction of [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (since Python 3.6, 2016-12-23) this can be written as

```
import datetime
f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}"
>>> '2017-06-15'
```

### Localization

Dates can automatically adapt to the local language and culture if you use them the right way, but it's a bit complicated. Maybe for another question on SO(Stack Overflow) ;-)

Comment: BTW Almost every data type in python is a class (except immutables, but they can be subclassed) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby

Comment: What do you mean "almost" ? str and int have a __class__ attribute, which contains 'type', therefor there are class themself, as they are instances of type metaclass.

Comment: This is exactly the question of terminology: type != class?, i.e. is it enough to have type attribute (provide type inference mechanism to be qualified for an object) or should entity behave as an object. I am trying to resolve this for myself here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/164570/formal-definition-for-term-pure-oo-language

Comment: If you are an instance of a class, you are an object. Why would you need it to be more complicated ?

Comment: To understand how python implements OO paradigm. Of course the cool part about programming python - that you don't even have to know that date is an object or what OOP is - you can just write a piece of code and be happy about the fact that it works. I think asking question "what is an object?" leads to learning theory. I don't think there is a guarantee OOP will improve programming skill though - it is only a theoretical aspect that just eventually may. E.g. knowing that one can implement/achieve OO behavior without type inference (a=1;issubclass(type(a),int) is inferring a type) is cool.

Comment: Every value in Python is an object. Every object has a type. ["type" == "class"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162578/python-terminology-class-vs-type) formally (also see `inspect.isclass` to make sure). People tend to say "type" for built-ins and "class" for the rest, but that's not important

Comment: I think the PEP3101 section should get moved closer to the top, and examples including strftime should be moved to the bottom in an appendix saying "If you're on an old version..."

Comment: Can you change your answer to python-3.x, please?

Comment: The author of this answer should consider a career in updating the core Python documentation, the quality of which is the ultimate cause of so many such questions ;)

Comment: use in this case:                             telegram_message="""\"
                            <b>Critical_Open: """+f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}"+"""</b> 
                            <pre>Order """+thresholds[0]['name']+""" """+thresholds[0]['describe']+""" </pre>
                            <code>more 10 s</code>
                            \""""

Comment: I know I am like, 13 years late, but in Python 3, you have to use ```print``` with brackets. So, it should be ```print(anything you want to print)```.

Answer (score 422):

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

**Edit:**

After [Cees' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066760/7487335), I have started using time as well:

```
import time
print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: You can use from `datetime import datetime`,  and then `print datetime().now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`.  Only a syntax difference.

Comment: `from datetime import date; date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` still looks unpythonic to me, but that's the best without `import time`. I think the datetime module is for date math.

Comment: my favorite is `from datetime import datetime as dt` and now we can play with `dt.now()`

Answer (score 202):

The `date`, `datetime`, and `time` objects all support a `strftime(format)` method,
to create a string representing the time under the control of an explicit format
string.

Here is a list of the format codes with their directive and meaning.

```
%a  Locale’s abbreviated weekday name.
%A  Locale’s full weekday name.      
%b  Locale’s abbreviated month name.     
%B  Locale’s full month name.
%c  Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.   
%d  Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].    
%f  Microsecond as a decimal number [0,999999], zero-padded on the left
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].    
%I  Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12].    
%j  Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366].   
%m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].   
%M  Minute as a decimal number [00,59].      
%p  Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.
%S  Second as a decimal number [00,61].
%U  Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week)
%w  Weekday as a decimal number [0(Sunday),6].   
%W  Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week)
%x  Locale’s appropriate date representation.    
%X  Locale’s appropriate time representation.    
%y  Year without century as a decimal number [00,99].    
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.   
%z  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM.
%Z  Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).    
%%  A literal '%' character.
```

This is what we can do with the datetime and time modules in Python

```
import time
import datetime

print "Time in seconds since the epoch: %s" %time.time()
print "Current date and time: ", datetime.datetime.now()
print "Or like this: ", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M")

print "Current year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
print "Month of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")
print "Week number of the year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%W")
print "Weekday of the week: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%w")
print "Day of year: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%j")
print "Day of the month : ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%d")
print "Day of week: ", datetime.date.today().strftime("%A")
```

That will print out something like this:

```
Time in seconds since the epoch:    1349271346.46
Current date and time:              2012-10-03 15:35:46.461491
Or like this:                       12-10-03-15-35
Current year:                       2012
Month of year:                      October
Week number of the year:            40
Weekday of the week:                3
Day of year:                        277
Day of the month :                  03
Day of week:                        Wednesday
```

Comment: This solved my issue where the "more-upvoted-answers" didn't.  But my issue was different than the OPs.  I wanted months printed as text ("February" rather than "2")

Answer (score 81):

Use date.strftime. The formatting arguments are [described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

This one is what you wanted:

```
some_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This one takes Locale into account. (do this)

```
some_date.strftime('%c')
```

Answer (score 49):

This is shorter:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
'2013-11-19 09:38'
```

Answer (score 31):

```
# convert date time to regular format.

d_date = datetime.datetime.now()
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
print(reg_format_date)

# some other date formats.
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(reg_format_date)
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(reg_format_date)
```

> OUTPUT

```
2016-10-06 01:21:34 PM
06 October 2016 01:21:34 PM
2016-10-06 13:21:34
```

Answer (score 28):

Or even

```
from datetime import datetime, date

"{:%d.%m.%Y}".format(datetime.now())
```

Out: '25.12.2013

or

```
"{} - {:%d.%m.%Y}".format("Today", datetime.now())
```

Out: 'Today - 25.12.2013'

```
"{:%A}".format(date.today())
```

Out: 'Wednesday'

```
'{}__{:%Y.%m.%d__%H-%M}.log'.format(__name__, datetime.now())
```

Out: '__main____2014.06.09__16-56.log'

Answer (score 20):

Simple answer -

```
datetime.date.today().isoformat()
```

Answer (score 10):

With type-specific [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) string formatting (see [nk9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20776958/1619432) using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).) in a [Formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (since Python 3.6, 2016-12-23):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}"
'2017-06-15'
```

The date/time format directives are not documented as part of the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) but rather in `date`, `datetime`, and `time`'s [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) documentation. The are based on the 1989 C Standard, but include some ISO 8601 directives since Python 3.6.

Comment: strftime doesn't really include an "ISO 8601 output". There are "directives", but only for specific tokens like "day of week", not a whole ISO 8601 timestamp, which I've always found annoying.

Comment: ```f"{datetime.datetime.now().astimezone():%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f}"[:-3]+f"{datetime.datetime.now().astimezone():%z}"``` to include milliseconds and timezone as well

Answer (score 8):

I hate the idea of importing too many modules for convenience. I would rather work with available module which in this case is `datetime` rather than calling a new module `time`.

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2015, 04, 01, 11, 23, 22)
>>> a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
'2015-04-01 11:23'
```

Comment: I think it'd be more efficient to do that in one line of code by doing `a = datetime.datetime(2015, 04, 01, 23, 22).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M)`

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert the `datetime` object to a `str`.

The following code worked for me:

```py
import datetime

collection = []
dateTimeString = str(datetime.date.today())
collection.append(dateTimeString)
    
print(collection)
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Come on ! Don't encourage a newbie to store a string instead of a date object. He won't be able to know when it's a good or a bad idea...

Comment: e-satis: If all you need is a string, what's the big deal? We store our firmware build dates as strings all the time -- sometimes storing a whole object is overkill when all you need is a simple timestamp (YAGNI and all).

Comment: Yes, in certains case it is. I just mean just a newbie won't be able to identify these cases. So let's start with the right foot :-)

Answer (score 6):

For [pandas.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)s, [strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.strftime.html#pandas.Timestamp.strftime) can be used e.g.:

```
utc_now = datetime.now()
```

For isoformat:

```
utc_now.isoformat()
```

[For any format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) e.g.:

```
utc_now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python you can format a datetime using the `strftime()` method from the `date`, `time` and `datetime` classes in the `datetime` module.

In your specific case, you are using the `date` class from `datetime`. You can use the following snippet to format the `today` variable into a string with the format `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
print("formatted datetime: %s" % today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

In the following a more complete example:

```py
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

# datetime in d/m/Y H:M:S format
date_time = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print("datetime: %s" % date_time)

# datetime in Y-m-d H:M:S format
date_time = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
print("datetime: %s" % date_time)

# format date
date = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print("date: %s" % time)

# format time
time = today.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("time: %s" % time)

# day
day = today.strftime("%d")
print("day: %s" % day)

# month
month = today.strftime("%m")
print("month: %s" % month)

# year
year = today.strftime("%Y")
print("year: %s" % year)
```

More directives:

[image: Python strftime directives from 1989 C standards]

Sources:

- [Format DateTime in Python](https://www.polynique.com/coding/format-datetime-in-python/)
- [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to get hours, minutes, seconds from a date object, does it? Shouldn't they always be 0?

Answer (score 4):

For those wanting **locale-based** date and not including time, use:

```
>>> some_date.strftime('%x')
07/11/2019
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
mylist.append(str(today))
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering the fact you asked for something simple to do what you wanted, you could just:

```
import datetime
str(datetime.date.today())
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to append it as a string?

```py
import datetime

mylist = []
today = str(datetime.date.today())
mylist.append(today)

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `print today` returns what you want this means that the today object's `__str__` function returns the string you are looking for.

So you can do `mylist.append(today.__str__())` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
my_date = date_converter.date_to_string(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to display the date as (year/month/day) :

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print '%s/%s/%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import date

def today_in_str_format():
    return str(date.today())

print (today_in_str_format())
```

This will print `2018-06-23` if that's what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick disclaimer for my answer - I've only been learning Python for about 2 weeks, so I am by no means an expert; therefore, my explanation may not be the best and I may use incorrect terminology. Anyway, here it goes.

I noticed in your code that when you declared your variable `today = datetime.date.today()` you chose to name your variable with the name of a built-in function.

When your next line of code `mylist.append(today)` appended your list, it appended the entire string `datetime.date.today()`, which you had previously set as the value of your `today` variable, rather than just appending `today()`.

A simple solution, albeit maybe not one most coders would use when working with the datetime module, is to change the name of your variable.

Here's what I tried:

```
import datetime
mylist = []
present = datetime.date.today()
mylist.append(present)
print present
```

and it prints `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand but, can use `pandas` for getting times in right format:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_datetime('now')
Timestamp('2018-10-07 06:03:30')
>>> print(pd.to_datetime('now'))
2018-10-07 06:03:47
>>> pd.to_datetime('now').date()
datetime.date(2018, 10, 7)
>>> print(pd.to_datetime('now').date())
2018-10-07
>>>
```

And:

```
>>> l=[]
>>> l.append(pd.to_datetime('now').date())
>>> l
[datetime.date(2018, 10, 7)]
>>> map(str,l)
<map object at 0x0000005F67CCDF98>
>>> list(map(str,l))
['2018-10-07']
```

But it's storing strings but easy to convert:

```
>>> l=list(map(str,l))
>>> list(map(pd.to_datetime,l))
[Timestamp('2018-10-07 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: A whole dependency to do something python std library has methods to do?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the shortest solution, which exactly matches your situation, would be:

```
mylist.append(str(AnyDate)[:10])
```

or even shorter, e.g.:

```
f'{AnyDate}'[:10]
```

PS: it doesn't need to be `today`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built-in `format()` function to format a date/datetime. For example:

```py
import datetime
format(datetime.date.today(), "%Y-%m-%d")    # '2023-12-05'
```

This is especially useful if you have a use case where you need a callable to format a list/sequence of date/datetimes. For example, for the case in the OP, we can map the `format` function to `mylist` as follows:

```py
mylist = [datetime.date(2008, 11, 22), datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 5, 11, 30, 5)]

list(map(format, mylist, ['%Y-%m-%d']*len(mylist)))   # ['2008-11-22', '2023-12-05']
```

or using the built-in `itertools` module, it can be written a little more efficiently as follows:

```py
from itertools import repeat
list(map(format, mylist, repeat('%Y-%m-%d')))         # ['2008-11-22', '2023-12-05']
```

Another use case where it comes in useful is when we want to convert a pandas column of datetimes and format them into strings. The pandas built-in `dt.strftime` is really slow but applying `format()` is much faster.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(mylist).apply(format, args=["%Y-%m-%d"])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
import time

months = ["Unknown","January","Febuary","Marchh","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
datetimeWrite = (time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y "))
date = time.strftime("%d")
month= time.strftime("%m")
choices = {'01': 'Jan', '02':'Feb','03':'Mar','04':'Apr','05':'May','06': 'Jun','07':'Jul','08':'Aug','09':'Sep','10':'Oct','11':'Nov','12':'Dec'}
result = choices.get(month, 'default')
year = time.strftime("%Y")
Date = date+"-"+result+"-"+year
print Date
```

In this way you can get Date formatted like this example: 22-Jun-2017

Comment: Too much code for something you could get in one line. With `%b` you will get the first three month words, and with `%B` the entire month.
Example: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S")` will return '2018-Oct-04 09:44:08'