# How to convert string to datetime in python

Tags: python

I have a date string in following format 2011-03-07 how to convert this to datetime in python?

Comment: `I had the similar question` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700118/getting-formatted-datetime-in-python-like-in-php

Comment: A Google search with the query `python convert datetime to string` returned 106.000 results!

Answer (score 25):

Try the following code, which uses `strptime` from the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2011-03-07','%Y-%m-%d')
```

I note that this (and many other solutions) are trivially easy to find with Google ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`datetime.date`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#date-objects):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = '2011-03-07'
>>> datetime.date(*map(int, s.split('-')))
datetime.date(2011, 3, 7)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-03-07', '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The datetime.datetime object from the [standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) has the datetime.strptime(date_string, format) constructor that is likely to be more reliable than any manual string manipulation you do yourself.

Read up on [strptime strings](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) to work out how to specify the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `datetime.datetime.strptime` and its sister `strftime` for this:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_obj = datetime.strptime("2011-03-07", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

It is used for parsing and formating from datetime to string and back.