# how to fix date column format using python

Tags: python, informatica

I am using python to pull some records from sybase db and writing it in  csv file  but am receiving the date in the format `JUL 22 12:00AM`, while I need it to be in `dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS` format. Could you please suggest any workaround?

we cannot change the query which is pulling the records,so formatting the query will not work.

the data in table is in `dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS` format .

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [`date.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) function:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime("JUL 22 12:00AM", "%b %d %I:%M%p")
```

I also recommend you to take a look in other Stack Overflow questions which may help you:

- [how to convert a string date into datetime format in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068269/how-to-convert-a-string-date-into-datetime-format-in-python)
- [How to convert string to datetime in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219970/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-in-python)

Comment: thank you for the solution, but I have the result in a csv file , the file contains other datatype columns also .How do you suggest to change the date format

Comment: Sorry but didn't understand what do you mean by having other datatype columns in the csv file. Could you explain it in more details in the question?