# Python : terminology 'class' VS 'type'

Tags: python, class, types, terminology

Just a simple question : when should I use the term 'class', and when should I use the term 'type' in Python ?

- is 'class' only for user-defined types, and 'type' for built-in types ?
- or now that [everything is a type](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/) ... should I use always 'type' even for user-defined classes ?
- ... ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is more or less historical: [they used to be different](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/) a long time ago, which has no practical implications anymore.

**Edit:** I use "`class`" when referring to concrete implementations and "`type`" in a more informal way, when speaking about high level data structures, application arcitecture etc. In *my thinking* a type is a more general thing, I don't think of every class as a distinct type.

Also, when I use metaclasses (very rarely) I speak of types.

Comment: And yourself, when do you use one or the other ?

Answer (score 15):

A *class* is a Python data structure that can be used as a template for instances of that class by calling it, e.g. `foo = Foo()`.

A *type* is a class that can be used as a template for additional classes by way of inheritance, e.g. `class Foo(Bar):`

Since Python supports inheritance, all classes can be used as templates for additional classes, which means that all classes are in fact types.

This is especially true since the advent of "new-style classes," derived from `object`, which unify the type hierarchy of user-defined classes with the built-in types.  Classes were always types, but now they are the *same kind of types* as the built-in types.

Although Python classes are types, I still find the distinction a useful one, so the terms are not entirely synonyms in my mind.

Bonus definition: a *metaclass* is a class whose instances are classes. In Python, these must be derived from the `type` class, just as new-style objects are derived from `object.`

Answer (score 3):

I use "type" to refer to the general case, but I switch to "class" when I'm speaking about attributes.

But it really doesn't matter which you choose.

> `{}` is of type `dict`. The `iteritems()` method of the `dict` class returns an iterator.

Comment: Ok ... I was just wondering this, because it is strange that 1 thing would have 2 names ... especially for a very neat language like Python !

Comment: Wait until you hit "constructor" vs. "initializer".

Comment: "constructor" vs. "initializer" isn't confusing at all. `__new__` is the constructor and `__init__` is the initializer.

Comment: @aaronsterling: Nope, that's not it.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question directly, but it might give you a sense of the difference between type and class.

```
class Card:
   def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=0):
      self.suit = suit
      self.rank = rank
card1 = Card()
```

`Card` is a class object, so its type is `type`.

However, `card1` is an instance of `Card`, so its type is `Card`.

Comment: well ... you could also say "Card is an instance of type" instead of "Card is a class object", and we're back to square one! Still no need for the word "class" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Within python code `type` is an `object` but `class` is a `keyword`, so, depending on the context, the words can have different meanings. People with a deeper understanding appear to be comfortable with this.

The `type` object be used to provide equivalent functionality to the `class` keyword.

```
class Base(object):
    _about_base = 'An attribute of Base'
 
class MyClass(Base):
    about_myclass = 'An attribute of myclass'

that = MyClass

this = type( 'MyClass', (Base,), dict( about_myclass='An attribute of myclass' ) )
```

`this` and `that` generated by the above code are identical, and are instances of the `type` class. You could perhaps say that they are instances of the `type` type.  `x = this()` is an instance of the `this` class/type.

```
x = this()
assert type(this) is type
assert type(x) is this
```

Answer (score -1):

You could say that an object at run-time is of a certain single type, but by means of (multiple) inheritance it can be viewed as belonging to several classes.

Comment: No because "by means of multiple inheritance" it is of all of those types as well. Which one type would you choose for it to belong to? class `is` type.

Comment: I like that run-time aspect; when creating new types, it is a class and at runtime when the concrete class was created, it is a type.