# Python: Class Name? Class Type?

Tags: python, class, types, repr

I read the `__str__()` vs `__repr__()` threads, and, somewhere on here (I can't remember where now) I saw the following code:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__)
```

This obviously prints the class name, so if I have a class like this:

```
Class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__)
```

It prints A (I can't make the angle brackets appear?).  If I take out the `.__name__` bit, it prints `<__main__.A>`  So now I am a little confused, as surely A is the type of Class A, not just its name, and I am not sure where the `__main__` bit is coming from as I have no `__main__` in the program (yet! - I do know about `if __name__ == "__main__"` and use it.)

So what is the difference between the Class name and the Class type, and is there ever a situation where they would be different?

Also, just wanted to add, pretty much everything I know about Python I have learnt from SA so far, even tricky questions have answers on here (accessing a superclass class variable from a subclass was my most recent google, and SA was there at number one again!!  Thanks everyone!)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running the code from within the python interpreter shell. In which case, the `__main__` is coming from the shell.

Sample code:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__)
... 
>>> A()
<A>
>>> class A:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<%s>" % (self.__class__)
...         
... 
>>> A()
<__main__.A>
```

On class name vs type, you can refer this post -> [Python : terminology 'class' VS 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4162578/1860929)