# int('123') in python - is it a function call or constructor call of 'int' class?

Tags: python, types, python-3.4

I am learning Python, and I am a little confused about the data types of Python. I am reading this line again and again.:

> 'Everything is an object in Python'

This includes integer, floats, string, sets, lists, etc. and when we write like this:  `[1, 2, 3]`, so we are actually creating an object of `list` class (or not)?  So, when we write an integer like `123`, does it mean it's an object of `int` class? But when we read in books it says that to convert a string into integer we need to use the `int` method?

But what I am thinking is that `int` is a class that also accepts the string object in constructor and then we get integer object, right?

So, is `int` a method or class in Python?

Comment: Try `help(int)` in the Python interpreter. It's a class.

Comment: thanks smarx, i understood :) i was beginner and different - 2 terms confused me :)

Comment: sidenote: `1`, `"x"`, etc. are literals.

Answer (score 9):

Yes `int` is a class (and it's also called a type; see [Python : terminology 'class' VS 'type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162578/python-terminology-class-vs-type)), and doing `int('123')` returns an instance of an `int` object.

However, (in standard Python aka CPython) for small integers (in the range -5 to 256, inclusive) the `int` constructor doesn't actually build a new integer object. For efficiency reasons the interpreter has a cache of small integers and the constructor simply returns a reference to the existing `int` object. This topic is discussed in the answers to [“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

Your book that calls `int()` "the `int` method" is being a tiny bit sloppy, IMHO. Pedantically speaking, `int` itself is a class, which is a callable object, and when you call a class that call gets automatically converted into a call to the class's constructor method (that is, its `__new__` method). But informally it's common to refer to `int()` as a function call or method call.

I almost forgot about the question in your first paragraph. When we write

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

the interpreter creates the 3 `int` objects and puts them inside a fresh `list` instance. (To be more precise, it puts *references* to the `int` objects into the list).

Using the standard [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) you can disassemble the bytecode for this operation:

```
from dis import dis
dis('a=[1,2,3]')
```

**output**

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             15 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

So even though we're "just" creating a literal list it's still a fully-fledged `list` instance object. Unlike some OOP languages, Python doesn't have any "primitive" datatypes that aren't objects, so literal integers and literal strings are also objects. Thus a literal string comes equipped with all the standard string methods. Eg,

```
print('hello'.lower)
```

**output**

```
built-in method lower of str object at 0xb72e7880>
```

shows us that the literal string `'hello'` has the standard `lower()` method.

Comment: Just a minor mistake (according to me) : `the interpreter creates the 3 int objects and puts them inside a fresh list instance.` It does not put the objects in the list, it's the references of the objects that is kept in the list.

Comment: @PranjalKumar I've updated my answer. I didn't mention references originally because we always work with object references in Python, and discussing that is a topic for another question. ;)

Comment: Do you know why the disassembly is different when a literal is used vs a class? For example dis("x = 1000") is different from dis("x = int(1000)")

Comment: @IKnewThat Why shouldn't it be different? If your code says to call  `int(1000)`, then the interpreter does that call & returns the result. Although `int(1000)` normally calls the built-in int constructor, it's possible to "shadow" that built-in name. Eg, consider what happens if you do `int = str; x = int(1000)`

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

> class int(x, base=10) Return an integer object constructed from a
>   number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a
>   number, it can be a plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point
>   number. If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.
>   If the argument is outside the integer range, the function returns a
>   long object instead.

So it's a class constructor that constructs an int object, depending on the given input x.

Comment: thanks DJanssens :), so when we create datatypes literls actually we are creating the objects of their classes ? ex:- x = [] so x is an list class object ? right , and similer in other datatypes, because that's why we can call method on them ? x.index('aa') ?

Comment: Yep @vikram, some objects are created that often that they made a literal for it. Because of that you can do x = 3, which will create an int object under the cover. Same goes for lists and any other python type.