# What situation makes a float-point like “1.0” (with .0) an integer?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I wanted to know if there is such a thing as a integer even tho it has a .0 decimal at the end. Is it considered a float or an integer?

Comment: @lurker - Python isn't statically typed, but it is strongly typed.

Comment: @TigerjawkT3 thanks for clarifying. I wasn't confident I had the correct term.

Comment: Somehow a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450129/is-there-a-difference-between-an-int-of-5-and-a-float-of-5-0 this kind of question can make sense with a javascript arithmetic implementation in mind.

Answer (score 2):

It's still a float. For example, do

```
print(type(1.0))
```

It prints `float`. In general, anything with a decimal point is a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

In a programming language, what it means to be a "float" versus an "integer" is to have a particular binary representation in the machine.

In Python specifically, which is not statically typed, if you write `x = 1.0` then `x` will be a floating point value. It is stored in memory using a floating point representation, such as [IEEE-754](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). If you write `x = 1`, then x will be an integer. You are telling Python which representation of 1 you want. If you were writing in C and you write, `int x = 1.0`, then `x` would still be an integer, since the compiler knows you want `x` to be an integer, and the compiler will convert it or generate code to do so.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a different behaviour could occur even with same internal representation. The type governs the behavior. Of course, understanding internal representation is important too: float behavior is tightly coupled to the fact that it has a limited number of significand bits.