# python: why does `type(super())` return <class 'super'>?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, super

A short inheritance example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname
 
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        super().__init__(fname, lname) 
        print(type(super()))
```

Now entering `Student("test", "name")` will result in `<class 'super'>` being printed to the console. I'm not familiar with this format. When I do `type(int)` I see the type as `type`, not as `<class 'int'>`.  Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: try to see what `type(int())` gives you

Comment: @bdbd oh shoot, thanks. So what does this mean exactly? Entering `int()` by itself just returns 0, presumably because that's the default. So why doesn't `type(int())` return `int`, seeing as `int()` evaluates to an int? (`int() + 2` works just fine, so it does seem like `int()` is returning an int and not something else)

Comment: "So why doesn't type(int()) return int" - it does.

Comment: As mentioned, it does return `int`, and `int` is actually a `class`, so you are trying to print the type of the class definition with `type(int)`, and the class instance with `type(int())` :)

Comment: I got curious as well why `type(int)` returns `type` instead of `class`, but here's some history for us:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162578/python-terminology-class-vs-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super),

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of `type`.

This proxy object is of type `super`; assuming `super_object = super()`, then `type(super_object)` returns a type object that describes the class to which all super objects belong to. Just like `type(0)` returns a type object that describes integers. `<class 'int'>` is how this type object prints itself. Fun fact: you already know this object.

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> type(0)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(0) == int
True
```

Note that in Python, constructor for a class is the type object itself. So when you write `int()`, you are constructing a new object of type `int`, just like when you write `Student("test", "name")`, you are constructing a new object of type `Student`. And so it is with `super` as well:

```
>>> type(super()) == super
True
```

---

To round out this answer, I will note something very, very obvious, but possibly worth mentioning here just in case. A variable might, and often does, differ from how its value is displayed. When you say

```
x = 3
print(x)
```

you don't expect the answer to be `x`, but `3`, because that is the way the value inside `x` displays itself (via `int.__str__` method). `int` is just another variable, one that happens to contain the integer type object. This type object displays itself as `<class 'int'>`, not `int`. `int` is just a variable name.

```
>>> my_shiny_number = int
>>> my_shiny_number()
0
>>> type(my_shiny_number())
<class 'int'>
```

And conversely (and please never ever do this in real code, this is for illustration purposes only):

```
>>> int = str
>>> int()
''
>>> type(int())
<class 'str'>
```