# Format a datetime into a string with milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, string-formatting, milliseconds

How can I format a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object as a string with milliseconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python

Comment: Please write a title that describes your problem and try to keep your question clear and to the point.

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that extra precision is often just fine. For example, Java's `Instant.parse` can parse represenation created with `strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')`

Answer (score 654, accepted):

To get a date string with milliseconds, use `[:-3]` to trim the last three digits of `%f` (microseconds):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
'2022-09-24 10:18:32.926'
```

Or shorter:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow().strftime('%F %T.%f')[:-3]
'2022-09-24 10:18:32.926'
```

See the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for more "`%`" format codes and the [`strftime(3)` man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/strftime.3#DESCRIPTION) for the full list.

Comment: Note, if you want to use `import datetime` instead of `from datetime import datetime`, you'll have to use this: `datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")`

Comment: In case microseconds are 0, in windows 2.7 implementation microseconds are not printed out so it trims seconds :(

Comment: @cabbi, you could use this instead: `(dt, micro) = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').split('.') ; dt = "%s.%03d" % (dt, int(micro) / 1000) ; print dt`.  I added this as an answer.

Comment: note that this truncates, not rounds to milliseconds

Comment: `(dt, micro) = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').split('.') ; dt = "%s.%03d" % (dt, round(int(micro) / 1000.0)) ; print dt`

Comment: As gens mentions, won't this get it wrong it the first drops number is >=5?. In fact if the usec part is > 999500, then you will never get the time right by fiddling with microseconds part

Comment: @gens  for time, truncation is preferred to rounding.  E.g. 07:59:59.999 should be truncated to 07:59:59 or 07:59 instead of rounding to 08:00:00 or 08:00, just as 07:59:59 should be truncated to 07:59 instead of rounding to 08:00.

Comment: I like this solution most, because it tries to use the same format string for parsing and representing the dates. Nevertheless, I am not able to use the %z format specifier at the end for the timezone. I think there should be another format specifier for the miliseconds... for example %F.

Comment: @gens the [datetime.isoformat(sep='T', timespec='auto')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) which is suggested in [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56074397/2932052) does the same: truncation. Maybe this helps locating timestamps via text search?

Comment: nitpick: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` == `%F %T.%f`

Comment: Where is the `%F %T` documented? I can't find it in the Python's page for `datetime`. Is it deprecated? It works even in Python 3.10, though. I do see it in pages on POSIX datetime format codes.

Comment: @m01010011 At the bottom of the linked Python docs, it mentions to look at the manpage for more.

Comment: When I use the code from this answer my file name looks like this: `2024-02-17 11/22/38` (slashes instead of colons!). Here is my code: `timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')`. Using `.` or `_` works, but not `:` for some reason. Hah!

Answer (score 163):

With Python 3.6+, you can set [`isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)'s `timespec`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow().isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')
'2019-05-10 09:08:53.155'
```

Comment: Useful with timezone too: 
date = datetime(2019,5,10)
date_with_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Rome').localize(date)
date_with_tz.isoformat(sep='T', timespec='milliseconds')
output: '2019-05-10T00:00:00.000+02:00'

Comment: This looks cleaner than the `[:-3]` in the accepted answer, but you should know that it seemingly does the same `>>> datetime.fromisoformat('2021-12-08 20:00:00.678900').isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')` leads to `'2021-12-08 20:00:00.678'`. Is the truncation specified in ISO standard or is it just a bug? The implementation uses integer division: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/99c72326d245fb604609a87a51ef1ad0845467b7/Lib/datetime.py#L174

Comment: As per Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#cite_note-37), "Separating date and time parts with other characters such as space is not allowed in ISO 8601, but allowed in its profile RFC 3339", so its a good idea to add something like 'T' as separator, and "If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space" (excerpt from Wikipedia).

Answer (score 35):

[@Cabbi raised the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds/71715115#comment54999511_18406412) that on some systems (Windows with [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)), the microseconds format `%f` may **incorrectly give `"0"`**, so it's not portable to simply trim the last three characters. Such systems do not follow the behavior specified by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

| Directive | Meaning | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| %f | Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded to 6 digits. | 000000, 000001, …, 999999 |

The following code carefully formats a timestamp with milliseconds:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> (dt, micro) = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').split('.')
>>> "%s.%03d" % (dt, int(micro) / 1000)
'2016-02-26 04:37:53.133'
```

To get the exact output that the OP wanted, we have to strip punctuation characters:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> (dt, micro) = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f').split('.')
>>> "%s%03d" % (dt, int(micro) / 1000)
'20160226043839901'
```

Comment: What I'am actually doing is this: print '%s.%03d'%(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), int(dt.microsecond/1000))

Comment: agree with @cabbi, there's no need to convert back and forth with string and int

Answer (score 31):

Using [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
'20220402055654344968'
```

Comment: FYI, this prints microseconds as the last 6 digits.  Add `[:-3]` to the end to drop the last 3 digits so that it is only displaying milliseconds.

Comment: microseconds can be less than 6 digits, so [:-3] is printing out wrong milliseconds

Comment: what if we have timezone?

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris for timezone checkout Lorenzo's answer

Answer (score 11):

Use `[:-3]` to remove the 3 last characters since `%f` is for microseconds:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
'2013/12/04 16:50:03.141'
```

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, if microseconds are 0 then the ".123455" portion may be printed as ".0", causing truncation of the last 3 chars to eat the low seconds digit and ".0".

Answer (score 6):

In python 3.6 and above using [python f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

print(f"{dt:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}.{dt.microsecond // 1000:03d}")
```

The code specific to format milliseconds is:

```
{dt.microsecond // 1000:03d}
```

The format string `{:03d}` and microsecond to millisecond conversion `// 1000` is from `def _format_time` in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py that is used for [datetime.datetime.isoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).

Answer (score 5):

```
import datetime

# convert string into date time format.

str_date = '2016-10-06 15:14:54.322989'
d_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(d_date)
print(type(d_date)) # check d_date type.


# convert date time to regular format.

reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print(reg_format_date)

# some other date formats.
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
print(reg_format_date)
reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(reg_format_date)
```

> <<<<<< OUTPUT >>>>>>>

```
2016-10-06 15:14:54.322989    
<class 'datetime.datetime'>    
06 October 2016 03:14:54 PM    
2016-10-06 03:14:54 PM    
2016-10-06 15:14:54
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you're looking for something that is faster than datetime.datetime.strftime(), and are essentially stripping the non-alpha characters from a utc timestamp.

You're approach is marginally faster, and I think you can speed things up even more by slicing the string:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t=timeit.Timer('datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")','''
... from datetime import datetime''')
>>> t.timeit(number=10000000)
116.15451288223267

>>> def replaceutc(s):
...     return s\
...         .replace('-','') \
...         .replace(':','') \
...         .replace('.','') \
...         .replace(' ','') \
...         .strip()
... 
>>> t=timeit.Timer('replaceutc(str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))','''
... from __main__ import replaceutc
... import datetime''')
>>> t.timeit(number=10000000)
77.96774983406067

>>> def sliceutc(s):
...     return s[:4] + s[5:7] + s[8:10] + s[11:13] + s[14:16] + s[17:19] + s[20:]
... 
>>> t=timeit.Timer('sliceutc(str(datetime.utcnow()))','''
... from __main__ import sliceutc
... from datetime import datetime''')
>>> t.timeit(number=10000000)
62.378515005111694
```

Comment: @oxtopus Good work. Personally, I don't use **timeit** anymore for simple measuring of time. It's strange that the ratios of times are different with your code: 1 - 0.67 - 0.53 and with mine: 1 - 0.35 - 0.20 , for the methods **strftime** - **replace** - **slicing**

Comment: Maybe something to do with the str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) being called in each iteration of the test vs setting it once?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.11 (maybe older version support it too) it can be done with `isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')`

From `datetime.py`:

> The optional argument timespec specifies the number of additional
> terms of the time to include. Valid options are 'auto', 'hours',
> 'minutes', 'seconds', 'milliseconds' and 'microseconds'.

```py
>>> datetime.now().isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
'2023-12-01T10:34:18.657'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import clock

t = datetime.utcnow()
print 't == %s    %s\n\n' % (t,type(t))

n = 100000

te = clock()
for i in xrange(1):
    t_stripped = t.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
print clock()-te
print t_stripped," t.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')"

print

te = clock()
for i in xrange(1):
    t_stripped = str(t).replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','').replace(' ','')
print clock()-te
print t_stripped," str(t).replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','').replace(' ','')"

print

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    t_stripped = str(t).translate(None,' -:.')
print clock()-te
print t_stripped," str(t).translate(None,' -:.')"

print

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    s = str(t)
    t_stripped = s[:4] + s[5:7] + s[8:10] + s[11:13] + s[14:16] + s[17:19] + s[20:] 
print clock()-te
print t_stripped," s[:4] + s[5:7] + s[8:10] + s[11:13] + s[14:16] + s[17:19] + s[20:] "
```

result

```
t == 2011-09-28 21:31:45.562000    <type 'datetime.datetime'>


3.33410112179
20110928212155046000  t.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')

1.17067364707
20110928212130453000 str(t).replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','').replace(' ','')

0.658806915404
20110928212130453000 str(t).translate(None,' -:.')

0.645189262881
20110928212130453000 s[:4] + s[5:7] + s[8:10] + s[11:13] + s[14:16] + s[17:19] + s[20:]
```

Use of **translate()** and **slicing** method run in same time
**translate()** presents the advantage to be usable in one line

Comparing the times on the basis of the first one:

> 1.000 * t.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
>
> 0.351 * str(t).replace('-','').replace(':','').replace('.','').replace('
>   ','')
>
> 0.198 * str(t).translate(None,' -:.')
>
> 0.194 * s[:4] + s[5:7] + s[8:10] + s[11:13] + s[14:16] + s[17:19] +
>   s[20:]

Comment: Nice! That is indeed cleaner without sacrificing performance. str.translate() actually faster in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the same problem but in my case it was important that the millisecond was rounded and not truncated

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def strftime_ms(datetime_obj):
    y,m,d,H,M,S = datetime_obj.timetuple()[:6]
    ms = timedelta(microseconds = round(datetime_obj.microsecond/1000.0)*1000)
    ms_date = datetime(y,m,d,H,M,S) + ms
    return ms_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python -c "from datetime import datetime; print str(datetime.now())[:-3]"
2017-02-09 10:06:37.006
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
datetime
t = datetime.datetime.now()
ms = '%s.%i' % (t.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), t.microsecond/1000)
print(ms)
14:44:37.134
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to store the time in a variable and do a little string manipulation, then you can actually do this without using the datetime module.

```
>>> _now = time.time()
>>> print ("Time : %s.%s\n" % (time.strftime('%x %X',time.localtime(_now)),
... str('%.3f'%_now).split('.')[1])) # Rounds to nearest millisecond
Time : 05/02/21 01:16:58.676

>>>
```

%.3f will round to out put the nearest millisecond, if you want more or less precision just change the number of decimal places

```
>>> print ("Time : %s.%s\n" % (time.strftime('%x %X',time.localtime(_now)),
... str('%.1f'%_now).split('.')[1])) # Rounds to nearest tenth of a second
Time : 05/02/21 01:16:58.7

>>>
```

Tested in Python 2.7 and 3.7 (obviously you need to leave out the brackets when calling print in version 2.x).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `datetime.utcnow()` and other such solutions is that they are slow.

More efficient solution may look like this one:

```
def _timestamp(prec=0):
    t = time.time()
    s = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(t))
    if prec > 0:
        s += ("%.9f" % (t % 1,))[1:2+prec]
    return s
```

Where `prec` would be `3` in your case (milliseconds).

The function works up to 9 decimal places (please note number `9` in the 2nd formatting string).

If you'd like to round the fractional part, I'd suggest building `"%.9f"` dynamically with desired number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

#### Field-width format specification

The UNIX `date` command allows specifying `%3` to reduce the precision to 3 digits:

```sh
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N'
2022-01-01 00:01:23.456
```

Here's a custom function that can do that in Python:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def strftime_(fmt: str, dt: datetime) -> str:
    tokens = fmt.split("%")
    tokens[1:] = [_format_token(dt, x) for x in tokens[1:]]
    return "".join(tokens)

def _format_token(dt: datetime, token: str) -> str:
    if len(token) == 0:
        return ""
    if token[0].isnumeric():
        width = int(token[0])
        s = dt.strftime(f"%{token[1]}")[:width]
        return f"{s}{token[2:]}"
    return dt.strftime(f"%{token}")
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> strftime_("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3f", datetime.now())
'2022-01-01 00:01:23.456'
```

NOTE: `%%` is not supported.