# python stripping chars from list item

Tags: python, string, list, strip

I'm trying to strip characters from timestamp stored in matrix (or list of lists if you want). I want to extract the item and use it as a filename after stripping unwanted characters (it should stay unchanged in the original list). I'm quite familiar with stripping and other string operations I use it routinely, but now I stucked with this, I don't know what's happening, I've tried almost everything. I want to get '2011092723492' instead of original '2011.09.27 23:49 2'. In this example is just ':' to be replaced to make it easier. Am I missing something ?:

```
for x in FILEmatrix:
    flnm = str(x[4])               # or just 'x[4]' doesn't matter it is a string for sure
    print type(flnm)               # <type 'str'> OK, not a list or whatever
    print 'check1: ', flnm         # '2011.09.27 23:49 2'
    flnm.strip(':')                # i want to get '2011092723492', ':' for starters, but...
    print 'check2: ', flnm         # nothing... '2011.09.27 23:49 2'
    string.strip(flnm,':')
    print 'check3: ', flnm         # nothing... '2011.09.27 23:49 2'
    flnm = flnm.strip(':')
    print 'check4: ', flnm         # nothing... '2011.09.27 23:49 2'
    flnm.replace(':', '')
    print 'check5: ', flnm         # nothing... '2011.09.27 23:49 2'
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) does, and that's not how it works. Strings are immutable, so the result is returned from the method.

```
flnm = flnm.replace(':', '')
```

Repeat with the other characters you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!
I'm starting to see. So far i've performed stripping on datas from readline() so there's probably the difference. But what's the difference between string from readline() and the one from the list?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re
flnm = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', flnm)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty fast (if you want to strip those known non-alpha chars from the string):

```
flnm.translate(None, ' .:')
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python there is usually more than one way to do it.

But first, `strip` doesn't work the way you think it does.

```
>>> flnm = '2011.09.27 23:49 2'
>>> flnm.strip('2') # notice that strip only affects the ends of the string
'011.09.27 23:49 '
```

You could join characters that aren't rejected.

```
rejected = ' :.'
flnm = ''.join(c for c in flnm if c not in rejected)
```

Or just join digit characters.

```
flnm = ''.join(c for c in flnm if c.isdigit())
```

Or chain a number of calls to string.replace.

```
flnm = flnm.replace(' ','').replace('.','').replace(':','')
```

Or use `re.sub`.

```
import re
flnm = re.sub('\D', '', flnm)
```

Since strings are immutable, make sure you assign the result back to `flnm`.

**Edit:**

Even more ways to do it!

[Using `reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603658/python-stripping-chars-from-list-item/7603860#7603860) (from Ivan's answer):

```
rejected = ' :.'
flnm = reduce(lambda a, d: a.replace(d,''), rejected, flnm)
```

[Using `translate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603658/python-stripping-chars-from-list-item/7603860#7603860) (from oxtopus's answer):

```
rejected = ' :.'
flnm = flnm.translate(None, rejected)
```

I prefer oxtopus's use of `translate` as it's the most straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = reduce( lambda a, d: a.replace(d,''),[':','.',' '],flnm)
```