# Format seconds as float

Tags: python

I wish to output:

```
"14:48:06.743174"
```

This is the closest I can get:

```
`"14:48:06"`
```

with:

```
t = time.time()
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.gmtime(t))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [manual on `time`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/time.html#time.strftime) there is no straight forward way to print microseconds (or seconds as float):

```
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f",time.gmtime(t))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

However [`datetime.datetime` format](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) provides `%f` which is defined as:

> Microsecond as a decimal number [0,999999], zero-padded on the left

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
'14:07:11.286000'
```

Or when you have your value stored in `t = time.time()`, you can use [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestam()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
'12:08:32.463000'
```

I'm afraid that if you want to have [more control over how microseconds get formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406412/1149736) (for example displaying only 3 places instead of 6) you will either have to crop the text (using `[:-3]`):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
'12:08:32.463'
```

Or format it by hand:

```
>>> '.{:03}'.format(int(dt.microsecond/1000))
'.463'
```