# Set precision for milliseconds in datetime string: Python

Tags: python

I have a datetime string "2017-02-14T18:21:14.080+05:30".
The code I used is

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
print parse("2017-02-14T18:21:14.080+05:30")
```

The datetime.datetime object I get is

```
2017-02-14 18:21:14.080000+05:30
```

Is there anyway python allows me to set the precision of the milliseconds value displayed before timezone info to 3 in order to get the output as

```
2017-02-14 18:21:14.080+05:30
```

Comment: Why do you care how its printed as long as the value is correct?

Comment: The value is correct, but the program to which the output is being fed into requires it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to ask Python to display dates with milliseconds.
You'll have to do a bit of string manipulation to get the desired result:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime as DT
date = parse("2017-02-14T18:21:14.080+05:30")
microsecond = date.microsecond
millisecond = int(round(microsecond/1000))
print(str(date).replace('.{:06d}'.format(microsecond), 
                        '.{:03d}'.format(millisecond)))
```

yields

```
2017-02-14 18:21:14.080+05:30
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7588511/190597) for solutions and
discussion of how to convert microseconds to milliseconds. Note that one of the
difficulties is that `date.microsecond` may return a number with fewer than 6
digits, and if microseconds are 0, on some OSes, `str(date)` may [drop the
microseconds altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds#comment54999511_18406412)). This
is why some pains were taken above to format microseconds to 6 digits before
replacing with milliseconds formatted to 3 digits.

Using the code above, on an OS which drops microseconds when zero, no
milliseconds would be shown. If you wish to *always* show milliseconds formatted
to 3 decimal places, you'll have to build the date string from scratch:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime as DT
date = parse("2017-02-14T18:21:14.080+05:30")
microsecond = date.microsecond
millisecond = round(microsecond/1000)
utcoffset = date.strftime('%z')
utcoffset_string = '{}:{}'.format(utcoffset[:-2], utcoffset[-2:])
print('{}{}{}'.format(date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), 
                      '.{:03d}'.format(millisecond),
                      utcoffset_string))
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution suits my need. A friend of mine suggested string manipulation, but I wanted to know whether there existed some function to do this. Im new to python and searched a lot but couldn't quite get this done.

Comment: Solution 1 gave me an error that said ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'. Tried replacing d with f, but returned the same string. Ended up force converting everything into int and your code worked. Leaving the code that worked here, below. Thanks again.

microsecond = int(dt.microsecond)
millisecond = int(round(microsecond/1000))
print(str(dt).replace('.{:06d}'.format(microsecond), 
                        '.{:03d}'.format(millisecond)))