# Python - matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter, wrong time ticks on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert the x-axis ticks from samples to time in the format mm:ss.decimals. The idea is that one second contains fs=44100 samples, so the conversion should be something like

```
time.strftime('%S.{}'.format(sample/44.1%1000), time.gmtime(sample/44.1/1000.0)))
```

Here's the whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import time
import os
import librosa

filename = 'path_to_your_waveform'
s, fs = librosa.load(filename, sr=44100, mono=False)
s=s[0,0:2*fs]

formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda sample, x: time.strftime('%S.{}'.format(sample/44.1%1000), time.gmtime(sample/44.1/1000.0)))

t_tot = np.arange(0, len(s), 1)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
for i in np.arange(0,2,1):

    plt.rcParams["agg.path.chunksize"] = 10000
    axs[i].plot(t_tot, s, color='b', linestyle='-')
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(fs/2))
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.savefig(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'name'))
```

In the figure below you can see that the x-axis ticks do not make sense (the whole file is cut to exactly 2 seconds).

[image]

Comment: Please try to explain the idea behind `time.strftime('%M:%S:{}'.format(ms%fs), time.gmtime(ms//fs))`. This will either directly lead you to see where you're wrong, or at least allow someone to answer this.

Comment: I have just added this part.

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic. Why is it not something like `time.strftime('%M:%S:%f', time.gmtime(ms/fs))`?

Comment: It might be closer to the solution, but it is shown on the plot like 00:00:f

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215948/python-display-milliseconds-in-formatted-string-using-time-strftime

Comment: My post has been marked has duplicate, even though the solution in the other post does not work for my case and does not contain the plot ticks part.

Comment: You may show inside the question in how far it does not work.

Comment: It's already in there, I get exactly the same plot with the wrong time division.

Comment: Yeah, but `('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:{}'.format(time_in_ms%1000), time.gmtime(time_in_ms/1000.0))` is not the same as what you have in the question, right? So no wonder it gives wrong output.

Comment: I'm using this one: formatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda ms, x: time.strftime('%S.{}'.format(ms), time.gmtime(ms//fs)))

Comment: Yes. If you don't see the difference, maybe start by not naming the input `ms`, because it's not milliseconds. That may make it clearer where you're wrong.

Comment: Changed 'ms' to 'sample'.

Comment: Right. So now you see that while the correct solution needs time in milliseconds, you use sample numbers. So you need to convert sample numbers to milliseconds to apply the duplicate answer.

Comment: The x-axis is correctly divided now, even if it still shows the wrong format (i.e. 01.500.0 instead of just 01.500)

Comment: `"{}".format(int(x))` or maybe better `"{:03d}".format(int(x))`

Comment: That seems to delete the seconds and leave the decimals only.

Comment: The original question itself is answered in the duplicate. What you're asking in the comments (or after several edits of the original question) is just how to format a float as an integer in python. There are duplicates for that as well. You can sure ask a new question, but remove librosa and matplotlib from it, i.e. boil it down to the *actual* problem.