# How do I find the difference in milliseconds between two datetime objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have two datetime objects which are 02:49:01.210000 and 02:49:01.230000:

```
RA_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(obs_data['RA'][3], "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
RA_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(pred_data['RA'][3], "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```

How do I workout the difference between these two times in milliseconds?

I tried doing RA_1 - RA_2 but got the error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

I also tried using total_seconds() but got the error:

```
'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Comment: You don't have two datetime objects; you called `time` on them, so you got time objects. Why did you do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds might help

Comment: @user2357112 because I don't want to take the dates into account, I just want the times.

Comment: @MattHill: `datetime.time` does not support that, as time differences are ambiguous. Is 1 AM 2 hours after 11 PM, or 22 hours before, or 26 hours ahead? You need to resolve the ambiguity manually if you want some specific behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can compute the different between two `time` objects. It is a hack which involves adding the same date to both objects.

*By construction it assumes both times relate to the same day.*

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

obs_data = {'RA': "22:24:05.52" }
pred_data = {'RA':"22:24:05.60"}

RA_1 = datetime.strptime(obs_data['RA'], '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
RA_2 = datetime.strptime(pred_data['RA'], '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()

diff = datetime.combine(date.today(), RA_2) - datetime.combine(date.today(), RA_1)
diff.total_seconds() * (10 ** 3)
# 80.0 [ms]
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I've added a disclaimer that it assumes both times relate to same day, hence 11pm & 1am difference will be 22 hours, not 24 hours. feel free to accept if it works (tick on left).

Comment: It is also important to note that this doesn't handle DST and other weirdnesses.  But you can't really do that without date and timezone info, which we don't have here.