# Generate Time stamp with millisecond frequency in Python

Tags: python, timestamp

Hello I am analyzing vibration data, the output form my sensors just gives my the array values and cannot export the time stamping. 
Its a 10 Khz data which is 0.0001 ms.

Is there a way to generate timestamp values in python with this interval.

For example:
2018-05-21 00:00:00:0001, 2018-05-21 00:00:00:0002

Comment: Can you post the exact format you read the data in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a datetime into a string with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate time stamp in your aforementioned format: `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:uuuuuu` where `u` represents microseconds.

For `dt` being a datetime timestamp, you can use `isoformat()` function. Here, `dt.isoformat(timespec='microseconds')` will return your desired result (except that the final colon is turned into a decimal point, and that there is a 'T' between date and time).

If you really want that colon, use formatted output and fields from that datetime object:

```
"%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%04d"
      %(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond // 100)
```

Here are some sample code with inputs and outputs:

```
dt = datetime(2018, 5, 21, 0, 0, 0, 100)
print(dt.isoformat(timespec='microseconds'))
print("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d:%04d"
      %(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day,
        dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond // 100))
```

This outputs

```
2018-05-21T00:00:00.000100
2018-05-21 00:00:00:0001
```

Comment: @RajeshKumar Sugumar Do you want the first solution or the second? Does your program have to be of the form `[year]-[month]-[day] hour:minute:second:tttt` where `tttt` represent `0.1` of a millisecond?