# python: change time to int from "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"

Tags: python, datetime, influxdb

Can anyone help me covert the time into a format that influx db accepts.  The aim is to pass time (including milliseconds) to influxdb.

Thanks

Comment: is that a string?

Comment: By int you mean an epoch representation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a datetime into a string with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need epoch time for influxDB

**Try:**

```
import datetime
import time

t = "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
print( time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").timetuple()) )
```

**Output:**

```
1257874200.0
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need it down to the milliseconds.  I'm reading sensor data and taking many readings per a second.

Comment: But your source only has till seconds

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I know from the example on InfluxDB website that that format is accepted but I need to get it down to milliseconds.  Sorry for any confusion.  I'm creating the time on the fly within a python script.

Comment: You can use `%f` if you have milliseconds. Ex: `print( time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").timetuple()) )`

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can convert the string representation to a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, convert that to a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time), then convert that to an integer representing the [UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

time_str = "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
time_fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
dt = datetime.strptime(time_str, time_fmt)
time_tuple = dt.timetuple()
epoch = mktime(time_tuple)
print(epoch)
```

Output:

```
1257912000.0
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need it down to the milliseconds.  I'm reading sensor data and taking many readings per a second.