# How to convert user selected date time to milliseconds

Tags: django

How to convert user selected date time to milliseconds. I am rendering date time from HTML page and stored into datetime_obj variable. How to convert variable date to milliseconds.Help me to do that.

views.py

```
def datetime(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DatetimeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datetime_obj = request.POST.get('datetime')
            dt = datetime(datetime_obj)
            milliseconds = int(round(dt.timestamp() * 1000))
            print(milliseconds)
            return render(request, 'datetime.html', {})
    return render(request, 'datetime.html', {})
```

datetime.html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="datetime-local" name="datetime" >
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('datetime/', views.datetime, name="datetime"),
]
```

Comment: follow similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/7588511/7887883

Comment: They are using current date time. I want user selected date and times not current time.