# How to get the millisecond part while converting to date time from epoch using python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, epoch, python-datetime

I have a unix epoc time as 1571205166751

I want to convert it to date time in millisecond

The desired result should be 2019-10-16 05:52:46:751 AM

But using following code I am getting the result as 2019-10-16 05:52:46, not the millisecond part.

```
import time
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(1571205166))
```

How to get the millisecond part while converting ?

P.S. I want to covert epoch time, not any other format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a datetime into a string with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds)

Comment: @luis.parravicini The questions you referred the time which needs to convert is in datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 16, 10, 6, 30, 665979) format. Not in epoch format what I am looking for.
So please remove the duplicate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

```
epoch_time = 1571205166751

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time/1000)

dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %p")
```

output:

```
'2019-10-16 11:22:46.751000 AM'

Note:

%f is not supported in time.strftime
```