# How to get current time in microseconds resolution?

Tags: python, time

Is there any way to get the current time in microseconds resolution? specifically %y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f format?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410614/how-to-get-the-millisecond-part-while-converting-to-date-time-from-epoch-using-p/58411334#58411334

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *print* a datetime in that format just by using `strftime`:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()

>>> now
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 17, 12, 45, 58, 294795)

>>> now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
'2019-10-17T12:45:58.294795'
```

---

Note that this is a *separate* issue to the resolution of your clock, it *may* be less than a microsecond. You can check that as well by using:

```
>>> str(datetime.time.resolution)
'0:00:00.000001'
```

As per the output, my Linux box (and Python 3.7 on my Win10 box) has a one-microsecond resolution.

Comment: awesome. I know it answers the above question but can i add an additional query to this?
How do i get difference between those formats?

Comment: @Coder, not sure what you mean by difference between the formats. Do you mean, given two strings of the `'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff'` form, what's the difference between them? If so, I'd just ask another question since it's only related tangentially to this one. There's no limit to the number of questions you can ask here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should import datetime and then, use strftime to format date and time.

```
Import datetime

Now= datetime.now()
Print(now.strftime("%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Comlete the parenthesis with your desired format.