# display time series in ms in python

Tags: python, time, posix

I have posix times, e.g. 1572015698537 and want to convert into a human readable string format. I tried

```
import datetime

s = 1572015698537 / 1000.0

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

but this just displays

```
2019-10-25 17:01:38.000000
```

and hides the milliseconds. Can someone help?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds

Comment: Is it because of your `s` being forced into int?

Comment: where is it cast into int?