# Python date formats conversion

Tags: python, date

Is there any method to convert date from "dd Mon yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ" format in python?

For Example: Convert "17 Jan 2020" to "2020-01-17T00:00:00.000Z" format.

I have tried datetime.strftime() but I am not able to handle the input date format.

Comment: PIease post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime()` expects a date object, so the string will need to be converted to a date object before it can be altered by `strftime()`.

Use `datetime.strptime()` to convert a string to a date object: it uses the same syntax as strftime to identify the datetime elements of the input string.  In the case of "17 Jan 2020", that process would look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_string = "17 Jan 2020"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, '%d %b %Y')

print(datetime_object.date())  # a datetime object

formatted_string_output = datetime.strftime(datetime_object, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

Note that `%f` will output 6 digits (microseconds, not milliseconds): use something like the [solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406412/14884726) to tailor your output to match your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this quickly helps!

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime("17 Jan 2020", '%d %b %Y')
print(d)
```

The output is:

```
2020-01-17 00:00:00
```