# How to record from webcam using ffmpeg with precise time information of when it was taken?

Tags: image, image-processing, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I need to record from my 2 webcams and output each frame recorded into images. An additional requirement is I need the time when the image is captured (it has to be precise up to around 10 milliseconds)

Things I've tried:

```
ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -r $frame_rate -i /dev/video0 -vframes 100 -strftime 1 cam0_"%H-%M-%S".png &
ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -r $frame_rate -i /dev/video1 -vframes 100 -strftime 1 cam1_"%H-%M-%S".png
```

This is only good up to a second, so if 2 images are taken within 1 second, 1 is overwritten.

```
for i in [1..100]
    ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -r $frame_rate -i /dev/video0 -vframes 1 -strftime 1 cam0_%5d.png
    date +%s%3N >> time.txt
```

Then 2 scripts are run in parallel. The timing is now precise up to a millisecond but this degrades the performance a lot since ffmpeg has to be initialized again each time I call the script.

I also tried this

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -pixel_format yuv420p -timestamps abs -copyts \
   -i /dev/video0 -vf setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vsync 0 -vframes 10 \
   camera0-%5d.jpeg -c copy -vsync 0 -vframes 10 -f mkvtimestamp_v2 timings.txt
```

And here's timings.txt

```
1614427227518
1614427227718
1614427227818
1614427227918
1614427228018
1614427228118
1614427228218
1614427228318
1614427228418
1614427228518
```

This is good up to 100ms.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Regarding `%H-%M-%S` check if [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406412/2057709) is useful to you.

Comment: @VC.One Unfortunately, ffmpeg doesn't recognize the ".%f" option, so the file name it prints out is something like "12-34-56.%f"