# Why does not datetime object have a millsecond unit?

Tags: python, datetime

```
begin = datetime.datetime.now()
third = [third for third in third_list if third]
end = datetime.datetime.now()
diff = end-begin

print('time: ', diff.microseconds)
```

It has 'seconds' and 'microseconds'. Why doesn't it have a millseconds unit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds

Comment: Does 'end-begin' end with millseconds or macroseconds?

Comment: Are you curious about `datetime` or the `timedelta` object in `diff`?

Comment: @tdelaney I mean datetime.

Comment: [well..](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/datetime.py#L456-L457)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, its not there. But isn't milliseconds the same as dividing microsecond by 1000?

```py
>>> diff.microseconds
7948
>>> diff.microseconds/1000
7.948  #miliseconds
```

Comment: I hate to give you an upvote for stating the obvious, but there you go.