# How can I change microseconds in a datetime?

Tags: python

How can I change my code to new output?

My code:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.today()
print(x) 
# Old Output: 2021-12-15 12:03:16.151803
```

but I want to create new output (remove the `803` from `12:03:16.151803` and save whole new output `2021-12-15 12:03:16.151`)

```
# New Output: 2021-12-15 12:03:16.151
```

Comment: try adding `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm interested in leaving two digits after a full stop?

Comment: You should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds)`.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is by [`slicing`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) it

**Example**:

```py
x = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm interested in leaving two digits after a full stop?

Comment: Answer is edited check out the new answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace` method of `datetime` objects.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print(now)
# 2021-12-15 13:51:27.148999

modified = now.replace(microsecond=0)
print(modified)
# 2021-12-15 13:51:27
```

You just can not edit any value of a datetime object. `.replace()` method creates a new datetime objects having the modification you wanted.

Comment: yeah thanks you , but I wish like to make ``2021-12-15 13:51:27.148`` from ``2021-12-15 13:51:27.148999``