# xlwings cell value wrong

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

in excel I have a cell with the value
**1:23.456**
with the the format
**m:ss.000** (minute, seconds and milliseconds)

now I want to read the value with python xlwings and pandas:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

excelData = xw.Book(path)
data = pd.DataFrame(excelData.sheets[sheetName].used_range.value)
print(data[20][7])
```

but instead of **1:23.456** I get **0.000965925925925926** as the output.

How do I get the right number as the output? (1:23.456)

Comment: pandas read it as the actual value of the cell (you can test on excel, - just change the cell format to general). So if you want to have time in Pandas, you must convert the integer value to time.

Comment: not sure if it will help with the current situation, but you can try to read excel sheet to pandas directly, without xlwings, - pandas does try to guess the datatype of the column, or you can assign the type manually

Comment: Add this line to your code just after **excelData = xw.Book(path)**;  **print(excelData.sheets(sheetName)['<cell>'].number_format)** where <cell> is the coordinate of the cell in Excel with this value,  e.g. A1. It will probably print **'mm:ss.000'** which is the format of the cell in Excel changing the display from 0.000965925925925926 to 1:23.456.

Comment: @moken that works but how do I convert the float number with that format that the same number (1:23.456) gets displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a simple, built-in way to do this.  However, you can change the format once the data is in the DataFrame (I assume there will be a column of data that needs to be changed:

```
val = data[20][7] # Change this to the range of data you need to be altered.

(dt.datetime.min + dt.timedelta(val)).time().strftime("%M:%S.%f")
```

The number you are seeing is the ratio of the time to a full day.

The code above starts at the minimum time `dt.datetime.min` and adds on the time of your value `dt.timedelta(val)`, then converts this to the format you want (but with 6 decimals).  If you specifically want 3, you could follow the steps of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588511/format-a-datetime-into-a-string-with-milliseconds/57395466#57395466:%7E:text=Field%2Dwidth%20format%20specification)