# Convert date to natural language in python?

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

I would like to know how to convert the following date to natural language, including time zone in python?

input:

```
"'2012-09-27T02:00:00Z'"
```

expected output:

```
Wednesday, September 26 of 2012 Mountain Time
```

Thanks in advance!

Note Edit:
So far I tried [django humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/), although it doesn't handle very well complex date-time strings.

**Solution:**

Thanks for all the information. I ended up parsing the original string and using pitz and strftime like this:

```
    my_date = '2012-09-27T02:00:00Z'
    utc_date_object = datetime(int(my_date[0:4]), int(my_date[5:7]), int(my_date[8:10]),int(my_date[11:13]),int(my_date[14:16]),int(my_date[17:19]),0,pytz.utc)
    mt_date_object = utc_date_object.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Mountain'))
    natural_date = mt_date_object.strftime("%A, %B %d of %Y")
```

Output:

```
'Wednesday, September 26 of 2012'
```

Comment: There is a great [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python) on that already.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @KeithSmiley: How is that post relevant?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Ideally it should display the timezone Eg. EST, or PST, etc...

Comment: @ipegasus: That is not what I meant. I meant different languages and different cultures have different definitions of what is human readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Babel project](http://babel.edgewall.org/) offers a full-featured [date and time localization library](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/dates.html).

You'll also need the [`iso8601` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/) to parse a date-time string with a timezone correctly.

It either formats dates and times based on locale:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, time
>>> from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time
>>> d = date(2007, 4, 1)
>>> format_date(d, locale='en')
u'Apr 1, 2007'
>>> format_date(d, locale='de_DE')
u'01.04.2007'
```

or it let's you specify the format in detail. This includes formatting the timezone.

Putting the parser and the formatter together:

```
>>> dt = iso8601.parse_date("2012-08-25T02:00:00Z")
>>> format_date(dt, "MMMM dd, yyyy", locale='en') + ' at ' + format_time(dt, "HH:mm V")
u'August 25, 2012 at 02:00 World (GMT) Time'
```

Ordinals ('1st', '2nd', etc.) are a little harder to do internationally, and the [LDML format](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns) used by Babel doesn't include a pattern for these.

If you *must* have an ordinal in your date formatting (perhaps because you only expect to output in English), you'll have to create those yourself:

```
>>> suffix = ('st' if dt.day in [1,21,31]
...                else 'nd' if dt.day in [2, 22] 
...                else 'rd' if dt.day in [3, 23]
...                else 'th')
>>> u'{date}{suffix}, {year} at {time}'.format(
...     date=format_date(dt, "MMMM dd", locale='en'),
...     suffix=suffix, year=dt.year,
...     time=format_time(dt, "HH:mm V"))
u'August 25th, 2012 at 02:00 World (GMT) Time'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a custom string representation of your date using the `strftime()` method. strftime accepts a string pattern explaining how you want to format your date.

For example:

```
print today.strftime('We are the %d, %h %Y')
'We are the 22, Nov 2008'
```

All the letters after a "%" represent a format for something:

- %d is the day number
- %m is the month number
- %y is the year last two digits
- %Y is the all year

https://stackoverflow.com/a/311655

Comment: I'm not sure why you asked how the question I posted was relevant and then linked to the same question. Were you saying I should've explained it?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% the answer to your question, but this code might help you starting formatting time and date:

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFormat(dtime):
    if dtime.day in [1,21,31] : ending = "st"
    elif dtime.day in [2,22] : ending = "nd" 
    elif dtime.day in [3,23] : ending = "rd" 
    else : ending = "th"

    return dtime.strftime("%B %d"+ ending + " of %Y")
```

Comment: What about '1st', '2nd', and '3rd'?

Comment: edited to include those cases

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that..

Comment: Yeah good point, forgot about 21, 23, etc

Comment: You may want to explain about what you do with your code. Just a blob of code is not really an answer.