# How to convert timezone in Django app

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

How can I change a timezone in a datetimefield.

right now I have

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 16, 4, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

how can modify the tzinfo just for display not to update on the db.

Comment: Are you talking about printing it as a string? In which case, would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/311655/2620328

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for such things.

From the `pytz` docs, you can use `astimezone()` to transform time into different time zone, as example below.

```
>>> eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> utc_dt = datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
>>> loc_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(eastern)
>>> loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
'2002-10-27 01:00:00 EST-0500'
```

Comment: don't use `tzinfo` parameter for timezone with non-fixed utc offset e.g., it is ok to use it with `utc` (the utc offset is zero (always)) but it is wrong to use it with `eastern`. Use `aware_dt = eastern.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)` instead.