# Modify an xml-file using python

Tags: python, xml

I have got a file which begins with some lines which I'd like to remove till the line " < ?xml version="1.0"? > "
This line and also the following two lines should be replaced by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<TimeML xmlns:ns0="xsi" ns0:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://timeml.org/timeMLdocs/TimeML_1.2.1.xsd" xmlns:ns1="xmlns" ns1:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<DOCID>doc3</DOCID>
<DCT>Sun Feb 24 15:25:40 CET 2013</DCT>
<TEXT>*1*9*6*9*
```

Is it possible to add in "DCT" the actual date, in the same format?

And: At the end of the file, one line before "< /TimeML >", I should add "< /TEXT >". Is this possible, too?

I could already solve the first part of the problem, i.e. remove the part which I don't want:

```
with open(fileName,'r+') as f:
   contents=f.read()
   contents=contents[contents.find('<?xml version="1.0"?>'):]
   f.seek(0)
   f.write(contents)
   f.truncate()
```

Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date formating, you can take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python).

And for replacing the end of the XML file, you have several choices:

- Do as you did, replace `</TimeML>` by all your stuff, plus `</TimeML>`
- Or you can use some XML parser as [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2)