# I want to print date like this

Tags: python, string, datetime, printing

I want my code to print the date like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print now.day +  "/" now.month +  "/" + now.year
```

But the compiler says "/" is an invalid syntax.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one `+` before `now.month`:

```
print now.day +  "/" + now.month +  "/" + now.year
```

And then you will see that you have to cast `now.xxx` to string:

```
>>> print str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.month) +  "/" + str(now.year)
30/12/2014
```

You might also want to use the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to format dates:

```
>>> print now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
30/12/2014
```

Comment: Why I have to cast now.xxx to string?

Comment: because they are integers: try `>>> type(now.day)` you will see `<type 'int'>` not `<type 'str'>`. But "/" is a string.

Comment: That sad moment when someone comments *"got it"* and forgets to accept the answer. (I know that feel bro meme attached)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `+` before `now.month` and also you need to convert all the `now.` to strings.

```
>>> print str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.month) +  "/" + str(now.year)
30/12/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
import datetime
print datetime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

You can [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have already mention you need a `+` before `now.month`. But you can use `format` to make the answer look better

```
print "{}/{}/{}".format(now.day,now.month,now.year)
```

Always use format for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are tying to concatenate sting with int in your print statement. That is why your code doesn't work. 
But if you want to use your code you must do this way.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print now.day,"/",now.month,"/",now.year
```

otherwise, use the options that are offered here.