# How do you get the time and date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the date and time on python for a program I am writing, But I am unsure how to get them. I tried to do it like the following:

```
import datetime
import date
```

This usually works but now it just prints:

```
<module 'time' (built-in)> <module 'datetime' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\datetime.py'>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python

Comment: Thx, must have missed that when I searched @mrDinkelman

Comment: @bgporter I have edited it to make it unique, can you please take it off duplicate?

Comment: No, ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Formatted time: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')`

Datetime object: `datetime.datetime.now()`