# Print time value in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print the contents of my dictionary with actual time values (for example, '6:00 AM') from my workbook. I get a different time format when I print from 'TimeSheet' than I do 'From'. How can I get the actual time value to print.

[image]

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
for i in range(1, 57):
   From = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
   To = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
   Activity = sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
   TimeSheet = {'From': From, 'To': To, 'Activity': Activity}
   print(TimeSheet)
```

Current output:

```
{'Activity': 'ACTIVITY', 'From': 'FROM', 'To': 'TO'}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(6, 0), 'To': datetime.time(6, 15)}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(6, 15), 'To': datetime.time(6, 30)}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(6, 30), 'To': datetime.time(6, 45)}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(6, 45), 'To': datetime.time(7, 0)}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(7, 0), 'To': datetime.time(7, 15)}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(7, 15), 'To': datetime.time(7, 30)}
{'Activity': None, 'From': datetime.time(7, 30), 'To': datetime.time(7, 45)}
```

Comment: example output would be helpful

Comment: Looks like you want [time.strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Comment: Closely related: [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already stated, you can use `strftime` to modify the formatting of your time, like so:

```
format = '%H:%M %p'  # Hour, Minute, AM or PM
TimeSheet = {'From': From.strftime(format), 'To': To.strftime(format), 'Activity': Activity}
# {'From': '6:00 AM', 'To': '6:15 AM', 'Activity': None}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `strftime` (string-format-time).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 14, 17, 24, 27, 735835)

>>> datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d")
'2016 06 14'
```

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) on the subject is pretty extensive, and there's also this [convenient reference table](http://strftime.org/) for the format language.