# Date time format in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I need date time in this format in python.Without seconds and milliseconds.

2016-07-06 10:27

I am using python version 2.7

Comment: have a look at this: https://pymotw.com/2/datetime/

Comment: OK, so write some code to do that. Do you have a question?

Comment: This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python): `import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`