# string.format() stops working correctly in my script

Tags: python, format

I have this format string:

```
print "{u: <16}  {l: >16}  {lse: <19}  {active: <12}".format(...)
```

which works fine in the Python console, but when run in my program, it prints `<19` (literally) for the `lse` part. When I remove the `<19` in the format specifier for `lse`, it does work...

My data is fine, because when just using plain `{u}`, etc, the correct data is printed.

**Update** the field is a `datetime` field. How can I print a `datetime` field using the format specifiers?

Comment: Maybe this answer is [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python) ? `print "We are the {:%d, %b %Y}".format(today)`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a `datetime` object does not abide by the format specifier rules. When cast to a `str`, it works:

```
print "{d: <12}".format(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```