# Python scriptline to get date&time

Tags: python, json, xml

As part of an XML-file I would like to have the following format of timestamp-string:

```
<time_stamp>20170120 14:38</time_stamp>
```

In the python-script to generate this XML-file (as well as an equivalent JSON-file), the following 2 instructions get & print the info for date&time:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print 'Present Date & Time = ', now
```

The result of the print-line is like:

```
Present Date & Time =  2017-04-07 18:19:35.538690
```

As explained below the question, the first scriptline now=datetime.datetime.now() is apparently not suitable to get well-formatted info for the desired XML-line and for it's equivalent JSON-line.

**Question:** what is better replacement scriptline?

To put the timestamp-info into the JSON-dictionary and to print the result, I have following 2 script-lines:

```
DDS238_dict['time_stamp'] = now
print(DDS238_dict)
```

For that timestamp the printline has output like:

```
'time_stamp': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 7, 18, 19, 35, 538690)
```

Generation of the json-file and xml-file is by the following 9 lines in the python-script:

```
# Make JSON-file
with open('DDS238_dict.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(DDS238_dict, outfile)
# Convert dictionary to XML-file & print
DDS238_xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(DDS238_dict, attr_type=False)
print(DDS238_xml)
xml_output = open("DDS238_status.xml",'w')
xml_output.write(DDS238_xml)
xml_output.close()
```

For the generation of the JSON-file I get the following error-report:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 7, 18, 19, 35, 538690) is not JSON serializable
```

From the generation of the XML-file I get the following result for the timestamp-string:

```
<time_stamp>2017-04-07T18:31:14.664248</time_stamp>
```

**Answer:**

Helped by the hints a link in StackOverflow [ [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python) ] guided to a working solution:

**=>** add one extra scriptline for correct formatting of date&time, before putting the timestamp-info into the json-dictionary

```
dattim = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M')
DDS238_dict['time_stamp'] = dattim
print(DDS238_dict)
```

Comment: You could do `now = str(now)`, and manipulate the string to get the format you want.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Is it how to generate the time string in a certain format? If so [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

Comment: As can be seen by the added 'Answer', the hints helped to find a solution!