# Python execute multiple class modules using .format or lambda?

Tags: python, class, module, automation

I'll ask the question using an example code I'm stuck with. 
I have two questions but they sort of ask the same concept. 
I'm trying to print date/time using:

```
print(datetime.now().day, datetime.now().month, datetime.now().hour, datetime.now().minute)
```

**QUESTION 1:**
But I don't want to keep retyping datetime.now() all the time. Is there a way to do this in Python?

Something like this??

```
print("{day} - {month} - {hour}:{minute}".format(datetiem.now())
```

Obviously that's wrong but you get the idea.

**QUESTION 2:**
Or, is there a way to automate module call from a class like this:

```
for item in ['day', 'month', 'hour', 'minute']:
    print(datetime.now().item)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to format a datetime, you can do one of those:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()

print("{0.day} - {0.month} - {0.hour}:{0.minute}".format(dt)) # 25 - 4 - 16:49
print('{:%d - %m - %H:%M}'.format(dt))                        # 25 - 04 - 16:49
```

the second one uses the [format mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) with the [format specifiers for `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

to get attributes dynamically, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for item in ['day', 'month', 'hour', 'minute']:
    print(getattr(dt, item))
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q1, you could do something like

```
now = datetime.now()
print(now.day, now.month, now.hour, now.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this ?

```
datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %M:%H:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python) for a similar question someone asked. There is an example where they use str.format() like how you would like to.

```
print "We are the {:%d, %b %Y}".format(today)
```

For the other datetime directives, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is the documentation for it.

**Edit for Clarification**

As mentioned in the article above, strftime() and format() will work the same now as of PEP3101.