# How to convert date/time string to epoch?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, epoch

Have the following string:

```
"date Thursday June 03 12:02:56 2017"
```

What would be the proper way of convert it to epoch time?

Comment: What exactly is that suppose to represent? A string?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, yes. Just clarified it

Comment: Just a start, not a solution, but this thread may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python

Answer (score 4):

You can use `datetime.strptime()` to parse your date and then just do delta with the epoch:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

epoch = dt(1970, 1, 1)
date = "date Thursday June 03 12:02:56 2017"

epoch_time = int((dt.strptime(date, "date %A %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y") - epoch).total_seconds())
# 1496491376
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - only on Python 3.x, and the OP clearly tagged his question with `python-2.7`...

Comment: Oh nice, I was totally unaware that Python 2 datetime objects lacked a timestamp method.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.struct_time) structure by parsing with [`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.strptime) and then pass it into [`calendar.timegm()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) to convert *to* epoch time.

```
import time
import calendar
timestr = "date Thursday June 03 12:02:56 2017"
calendar.timegm(time.strptime(timestr, "date %A %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))
# returns 1496491376
```