# user friendly date format using python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Got in touch with a few thousand dates using the following format:

```
2017-10-23T03:36:23.337+02:00
```

I only know that it's CET (central european time). Instead of trim the value manually, there is any solution that would give me this date in the format dd/mm/yy hh/mm/ss that I could use to subtract (find the diference between them) the dates without problems? Thanks for your inputs.

Here my code:

```
from_date="2017-10-23T03:36:23.337+02:00"
import time                
conv=time.strptime(from_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",conv))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

Comment: you want to convert that time to dd/mm/yy hh/mm/ss format?

Comment: @DRPK thats right, but that I could use it later to find the diferences between dates. So it needs to continue as a date. thanks

Comment: whats your code for that output format?

Comment: @DRPK just updated the post with it. The format of the date that was given to me is strange. It has for instance a T in the middle. Is it possible to convert it to a normal date? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With given format, you can use `dateutil.parser.parse` to handle it.

Here's some code:

```
d = "2017-10-23T03:36:23.337+02:00"
time = dateutil.parser.parse(d)
print(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H/%M/%S"))
```

The output is:

`23/10/17 03/36/23`

Comment: thanks for the reply. Whats the module? from dateutil.parser import parse?

Comment: It's a third-party module, you can install it with `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: And here's everything you need to know about it: http://labix.org/python-dateutil

Comment: didnt know about it. if it can parse that line into a correct date .. great! thanks!