# Convert specific timestring to normal time?

Tags: python, date

I'm currently working on a small project, but I got a problem, I don't know how to convert this `"2017-12-22T05:00:00+01:00`" time, to an readable time, I would like to get it to this format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`. Without success so far, is there something I can do to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to parse the input datetime string into a `datetime` object. Then convert the `datetime` object to the required format. The easiest way to do that is with the third-party [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/) package. You can install it with `pip`.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse('2017-12-22T05:00:00+01:00')
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 22, 5, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```

Converting to a new format can be done with [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2017-12-22 05:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help! This is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this question:
 [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

It's a very comprehensive answer with links to the documentations

Comment: It doesn't seem like an answer to his question, I think he meant string conversion to another string which would be formatted little bit differently. Parsing of first string would still be part of the answer.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. apologies

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same string each time, you could use something like this:

```
time_string = '2017-12-22T05:00:00+01:00'
year = time_string.split('-')[0]
month = time_string.split('-')[1]
day = time_string.split('-')[2].split('T')[0]
time = time_string.split('T')[1].split(':')
hour = time[0]
minute = time[1]
second = time[2].split('+')[0]
print(second,minute,hour,day,month,year)
```

(but there's probably a much better way to do it.)