# Passing today's date for a date picker field in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, date, selenium, bdd

I am trying enter today's date into a date picker field rather than just click the `today` button and below is how my code is set up, but not able to do so. I am using BDD framework.

And I input todays date

```
@When('I input todays date')
def step_impl(context):
    value_paystub_dateOfPayStub(context.webdriver)

Getting element of said date picker:
def get_dateOfPaystub(driver):
    element = None
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='chl.CustomerFinancials.primaryFinancialsForm.paystub.6134.DateOfPaystub']"))
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        logger.error("Date of Paystub element was not found")
    return element

Trying to enter today's date:
def value_paystub_dateOfPayStub(driver):
    currentdate = datetime.datetime.today()
    try:
        element = get_dateOfPaystub(driver)
        element.send_keys()  # to set focus on the selector
        element.send_keys(currentdate, "%m-%d-%Y")
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Unable to enter value into Paystub Employer Name field")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add html of you website

Comment: What is your expected date format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

Comment: @JeffC I am expecting to input it in mm-dd-YY format.

Comment: The link I posted above has a number of examples. You should be able to use one of them to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strftime` to format your date.

```
import datetime from datetime

element.send_keys(datetime.strftime(currentdate, '%m-%d-%Y'))
```

Comment: I will give this a try and report back, I appreciate you taking the time to reply.

Comment: Did this work for you? I can update my answer if there are any other exceptions occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Here we need to define the locator for the calendar field to accept data dynamically as below.

```
calendar = "//p[contains(.,'{}')]"
```

and then use the below code to fetch today's date and select the appropriate date

```
import datetime
current_day = datetime.datetime.now().day
driver.find_element_by_xpath(calendar.format(current_day).click
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tried using css_selector:

```
import  datetime

# Getting today's date
now = datetime.datetime.now()
tday = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")

# Selecting everything and clearing by backspace
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a', Keys.BACKSPACE)
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ID')
or 
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('ID')

#  Sending today's date
elem.send_keys(tday)
time.sleep(1)
```