# SQlite is not querying output correctly

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SQL statement, however it is including a date from October

The format from the csv line is 10/2/2017 17:32

Is it because my csv is incorrect?

Please help!

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Completion Status]= 'Incomplete' 
AND [Curriculum Name] NOT LIKE '%Phishing Training%' 
AND [Date Assigned] < date('now','-30 day') 
ORDER BY [Employee Department]
```

Comment: Do you mean CV (not CSV)?

Comment: csv file was converted to the database in which i'm querying off, sorry

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change the format of the date in your CSV. I don't think SQLite recognizes that format. Once you do that the answer from Olivier should work.
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

`now` (as of 17. Jan 2018) minus 30 days is `18. Dec 2017`. Since you want `[Date Assigned] < this date`, i.e. before this date, a date from October is correct.

Did you intend to write

```
[Date Assigned] >= date('now','-30 day')
```

i.e. return entries at most 30 days old?

Also, according to the official SQLite documentation, you should store the date as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`. See: [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: i giet it, thanks but now its pulling dates from September :(

Comment: You should store the date as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`. See: [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: can i create a python function to alter this?

Comment: See [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime) for parsing and [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python) for formatting. First parse the string from the CSV, then format it for SQLite.