# simple conversion between custom date/time formats in python (2.7)

Tags: python, datetime

I have looked far and wide to answer my question/solve my problem but I'm stuck.

I need to import a table of data, the first column of which, is composed of date/times like '20180214_145712'.  Eventually I would like to export this data to a format that I think will work well with MS Excel i.e. '2018-02-14 14:57:12'.

Now I found a scrap of code that seems to do exaclty this:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 14, 14, 57, 12)
'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)
```

Now when I input the first data/time value from my data file like so:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime(int(data[0][0][0:4]), int(data[0][0][4:6]), int(data[0][0][6:8]), int(data[0][0][9:11]), int(data[0][0][11:13]), int(data[0][0][13:15])
'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)
```

I get an error in my Jupyter notebook:

```
File "<ipython-input-72-d0bef0623630>", line 4
'{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

At this point I don't know how to proceed any further.  The format identifiers seem to be fine, I think my input data is fine i.e. just integers.  I checked on SO forum and found a useful post about the datetime module ([other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)).

Any pointers would be useful.

Rich

Comment: Have a look at datetime functions strftime and strptime. Use strptime to get a date object from a string and strftime to parse a datetime object to a string in desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)** module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = '20180214_145712'

print datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**Output**:

```
2018-02-14 14:57:12
```