# Add Date to the subject

Tags: python, yagmail

```
def send_email(status,message):
    yag.send(to=TO_EMAIL,subject="Test Subject: {}".format(status),contents=message)
    logging.info("Mail Sent!")
```

How do I add the current date DDMM format just before the subject line like:
0308 Test Subject ? Yagmail Package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
from datetime import datetime
def send_email(status,message):
    date = str(datetime.now().date())[-5:].replace('-', '')
    yag.send(to=TO_EMAIL,subject="{} Test Subject: {}".format(date, status),contents=message)
    logging.info("Mail Sent!")
```

Comment: glad to see this is what you were looking for, `+1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strftime` from the `datetime` module like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def send_email(status,message):
    yag.send(to=TO_EMAIL,subject="{} Test Subject: {}".format(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%d%m"), status),contents=message)
    logging.info("Mail Sent!")
```

Comment: Everything works correctly on my side in the format you wanted.