# How to change date format in python pandas from mm/dd/yyyy to dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column having data of dates having date format - mm/dd/yyyy and i want to change its format to dd-mmm-yyyy. Can anyone help me regarding this.

Like any code which make 10/12/2018 to 12-Oct-2018.

Also I need that it will not lose its properties. Like when i export the data in excel then after applying filter on date column it will remain as come under 2018 in drop bar and not in 12-Oct-2018.

Like in excel when i apply filter the it needs to show-

2018
2017 etc

and not like

12-Oct-2018
10-Oct-2018
5-Sep-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print date in a regular format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-date-in-a-regular-format-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the datetime format in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4):

Use `pandas.Series.dt.strftime` function:

```
import pandas as pd

time = pd.DataFrame({'TimeColumns': {0: '10/13/2018'}}) #create time object - in your case get column values

time['TimeColumns'] = pd.to_datetime(time.TimeColumns)


time['ModifiedTimeColumns'] = time['TimeColumns'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y') # change time formatting
print(time['ModifiedTimeColumns'])
```

Results:

```
0    13-Oct-2018
Name: ModifiedTimeColumns, dtype: object
```