# Importing csv to python with Variable Name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to import (read) a csv from a path. Each csv per day is saved as yyyymmdd_filename.csv in C:\

Using 
`pd.read_csv('C:/yyyymmdd_filename.csv')` I can import the file of a current date

However, I want to assign a variable `date = today()` and run the file to import the csv.

So I imagine it would look something like this
`pd.read_csv('C:/' + date + '*filename.csv')`

Is this possible to do using pd.read_csv? if not what should I use

Comment: Check out there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small code :

```
from datetime import date
today=date.today()
print(today.strftime('%Y%m%d') #'20190321'
```

And for your case , to get the whole way to file:

```
print('C:/{}_filename.csv'.format(today.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
print(f'C:/{today.strftime("%Y%m%d")}_filename.csv') #don't use the same quote inside and outside or it won't work, of course.
print('C:/'+today.strftime('%Y%m%d')+'_filename.csv')
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i also implement the today while importing my csv?

Comment: pd.read_csv('C:/{}_filename.csv'.format(today.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
or
pd.read_csv(f'C:/{today.strftime('%Y%m%d')}_filename.csv')
or
pd.read_csv('C:/'+today.strftime('%Y%m%d')+'_filename.csv')