# How to remove the additional time-zone added information from datetime string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

Silly Question, but couldn't find the proper answer.
I converted my datetime object from UTC to ist using dateutils.

```py
utc = datetime.utcnow()
UTC = tz.gettz('UTC')
indian = tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')
ind = utc.replace(tzinfo=UTC)
ind.astimezone(indian).replace(microsecond=0).__str__()
```

Output

> '2019-07-30 16:32:04+05:30'

I would like to remove the +5:30 part, how do I go about doing that, except splitting the string on '+' symbol, or how do I avoid it being added in the first place.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/311655/1622937

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly state your format via [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
>>> new = ind.astimezone(indian).replace(microsecond=0)
>>> new.strftime('%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S')
'2019 07 30 16:59:56'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply strip out the timezone from the datetime object by using `tzinfo=None`. The string representation will still be ISO8601, but with no timezone offset part.

```
str(
   datetime.now(tz=tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')))
   .replace(microseconds=0, tzinfo=None)
)
# '2019-07-30 16:32:04'
```

Comment: Are you sure? In any case, I've simplified my answer a bit more, by directly calling datetime.now with a specific timezone instead of using utcnow.

Comment: Apologies -- I missed the fact (in your original answer) that you were using `utcnow` rather than `now`.