# timedate reformatting

Tags: python

My Python script is currently writing out my date from the `timedate` module request as follows:

`2019-08-28 14:56:52.559047`

I want it to be converted to:

`Aug 28`

Comment: Did you try _anything_? It's a "datetime" not a "timedate" btw. Python has a `datetime` module exactly for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `datetime` module.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%b %d")
'Aug 28'
```

I'd suggest reading about the [datetime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime) module ([official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)) and [strftime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime).

Relevant SO question: [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did the trick!

Comment: @rahrahruby No problem. If you think I've solved your problem, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.