# Python code for 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' format

Tags: python

I need python code for 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' format .
The result would be like this '2019-07-27 12:07:00.0'

sample code that I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

from datetime import timedelta

timestamp=(dt.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %HH24:%MI:%SS.%FF')
```

Output:`2019-09-05 10H24:31I:57S.2019-09-05F`

Results should looks like `2019-09-05 10:31:57.0`

Comment: strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string just needs to be adapted - Python takes a single character to tell about the correct output - your repeated characters don't work like that.
Here is a corrected code example:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

from datetime import timedelta

timestamp=(dt.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

As you can see, I just removed some characters and wrote `f` in lowercase. The format characters that you chose already include padding and 24-hour format.

Example output: `'2019-09-05 12:27:45.416157'`

[For a full list of format characters, please check the linked python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), you should use the following format:

```
timestamp=(dt.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```