# How to format (succinctly) a date when returning django validation?

Tags: python, django

In django, I'm validating a date:

```
from datetime import date
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

if start_date < date.today():
    raise ValidationError(
        _('%(start_date)s must be on or after today.'),
        params={'start_date': start_date},
    )
```

where `start_date` is a `datetime` instance.

What do I need to write in place of `s` in `%(start_date)s` in order to format the date nicely; preferably as dd-mmm-yyyy?

Comment: `print(f'The value is {foo:%d-%b-%Y}')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Comment: Sorry I've made the question clearer.

Comment: try this: start_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`strftime(...)`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method as,

```
def validate_date(start_date):
    if start_date < date.today():
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(start_date)s must be on or after today.'),
            params={'start_date': start_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")},
        )

    return start_date
```

You will get the exception as,

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['**01-Jan-2020** must be on or after today.']

---

You can see the full set for format code that supported by `strftime(...)` method here, [*`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

---

#### Update-1

You can use the [***`str.format()`***](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method as,

```
def validate_date(start_date):
    if start_date < date.today():
        raise ValidationError(
            _("{:%d-%b-%Y} must be on or after today.".format(start_date))
        )

    return start_date
```

---

#### Update-2

as @Justin Ezequiel mention in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67606269/how-to-format-succinctly-a-date-when-returning-django-validation/67641536#comment119497116_67606269), you can use the **f-string** as

```
def validate_date(start_date):
    if start_date < date.today():
        raise ValidationError(
            _(f"{start_date:%d-%b-%Y} must be on or after today.")
        )

    return start_date
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way of doing this without changing the type of `start_date` in `params`? Sonmething like `%(start_date)d-%(start_date)%b-%(start_date)Y must be on or after today.'?

Comment: Are you into something like my *"Update-1"* section?

Comment: Not really. What I really want is a replacement for `s` in `%(start_date)s` in my program snippet. It might not be possible of course. Perhaps your way is the best way?!

Comment: You can't replace the ***`%s`*** with something else. In this situation, Django uses the ***`%`*** style string formatting ([old-style `PyFormat`](https://pyformat.info/)) to format the string

Comment: Personally, I'm wondering how the `str.format()` or `datetime.strftime()` methods are becoming *not succinct* to you :O

Comment: I'm nervous about changing the type of start_date in params.

Comment: In the end, all you need is ***a string***, nothing more, nothing less. The ***`%s`*** is something that converts to string with the given object, just like calling `str(any_dt_obj)`

Comment: If you are uncomfortable to call the `strftime` in the parameters, you can go for the `Update-1` and `Update-2`. To my best knowledge, this is a dead-end

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Had a chat with a colleague in the end (on this site too as Bathsheba) - completely agreed with you. Said that the %s as it appears in the ValidationError constructor is purely a Django thing, not a Python thing per se, and in the Django source code it maps to str.