# How do i get rid of the time in datetime function?

Tags: python

I wanted the output to be `yyyy-mm-dd` only, without the time. this is what i tried:

```
Begindate = datetime.strptime(Begindatestring, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(Begindate)
```

thank you

Comment: ```Begindate.date()```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Comment: thankyou, this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.strftime`:

```
print(Begindate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```