# Convert a datetime.date() object with underscores rather than hyphens

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to create a datetime.date object, but change the hyphens in the date to underscores. Is there a way to do this with datetime.date objects? Or would I have to somehow do this with the datetime object?

```
from datetime import datetime


date = datetime.strptime('2021-12-30', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

print(type(date))
# <class 'datetime.date'>
print(date)
# 2021-12-30

date_2 = date.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
print(date_2)
# 2021_12_30
print(type(date_2))
# <class 'str'> I want this to stay as a datetime.date object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` object you're referring to only exists in this shape: `datetime.date(2021, 12, 30)`. When you call `print()` on it, it simply turns it into a string and prints it:

```
> print(date)
2021-12-30
```

Which is to say, you cannot have underscores instead of dashes unless you decide to work with a strings. `strftime()` is a great way of transforming the date into a string. Otherwise you can use the following for the same effect:

```
> str(date).replace('-', '_')
2021_12_30
```

For more colour on Python strings and date objects, check out this answer: [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Answer (score 0):

print(date) in the first example is string representation of python datetime object handled by datetime.**str** method

date.strftime is function for getting the string representation according to the given format

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).